# Add syntax highlighting for [python-3.4]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The [python-3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.4) tag does not on its own trigger Python-specific automatic syntax highlighting in questions and associated answers ([sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26130644/1426065)). It's generally good practice when asking about Python (and is requested if you hover over the tag on the main site) to include both the generic [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, and a version-specific one as well ([python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), etc.) as there are many differences between versions 2 and 3. In my testing, all of the other recent version-specific tags highlight on their own; only this one doesn't. Version 3.4.0 was [released](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) back in March 2014, and while the number of questions tagged with it is relatively small, it is definitely growing as more people upgrade (it's also the default Py3 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

So, because many around here dislike questions without actual questions: Can someone please fix this?

Comment: In your testing? For future information, you can now just visit the [tag's info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.4/info) and see what language it uses at the bottom below the buttons. No testing required.

Comment: @animuson thanks for the quick reply! Don't worry, my "testing" wasn't too extensive, I just clicked on a few questions from my list of favorite tags.