# Apply Python syntax highlighting for [python-3.5]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The still-in-the-works Python 3.5 already has a tag on StackOverflow.

Can someone make the [python-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.5) tag trigger Python syntax highlighting?

Note: tag info pages for similar tags
[python-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2),
[python-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.1)
to [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7),
[python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3),
[python-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.1)
to [python-3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.4),
all end with the line:

> Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-py

Note: [the recent similar request for the `python-3.4` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272894/add-syntax-highlighting-for-python-3-4) was successful.

Comment: I would just merge all python-3.x into python-3 and be done with it.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus [none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-abitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3#comment33070330_19011259) of [those](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18035135/792066) are [version specific](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/213575) as the apply to [later versions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27385659/) of python.