# Python syntax highlighting for questions tagged [python-3.7]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

The soon to be released Python 3.7 already has a tag on Stack Overflow.

Can someone make the [python-3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.7) tag trigger Python syntax highlighting?

Note: tag info pages for similar tags
[python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x),
[python-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.1)
to [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7),
[python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x),
[python-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.1)
to [python-3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.6),
all end with the line:

> Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-py

Note: similar requests [for the `python-3.4` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272894) and [for the `python-3.5` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285834) were successful.

Comment: Any Python 3.7 question should also be tagged Python, IMO. For example, the first result that's *only* tagged with the version-specific tag is https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913467/3001761, which doesn't seem like a version-specific problem.

Comment: The link links to a page that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have set this to use Python syntax highlighting.