# Python syntax highlighting for questions tagged [python-3.8]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Python 3.8 has been out for about five months now.

Can someone make the [python-3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.8) tag trigger Python syntax highlighting?

Note: similar requests for [the `python-3.4` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272894), [the `python-3.5` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285834), and [the `python 3.7` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370187/python-syntax-highlighting-for-questions-tagged-python-3-7) were successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done now.

Thank you for citing evidence and providing a *prima facie* case: this makes my job easy.